# Default location of the execution status of an sh script which is scheduled in a cron

Tags: cron

I have a script scheduled in cron.d.  Where can I see the status of the script – whether it's run successfully or not?  Is it in a file – if nothing is explicitly mentioned to stdout, or stderr?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which distribution you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**For Debian (and derivates) with systemd:**

You can, for instance, look into `/var/log/syslog`. Like this:

```
sudo grep -i 'cron' /var/log/syslog
```

Also, to check the current status of the cron daemon, you can do:

```
sudo systemctl status cron
```

Which will give you an output like this:

```
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since mon 2016-08-22 09:02:16 CEST; 1 months 5 days ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 570 (cron)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─570 /usr/sbin/cron -f

sep 27 07:09:01 server CRON[24945]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/s...)
sep 27 07:09:01 server CRON[24944]: pam_unix(cron:session): session cl...t
sep 27 07:17:01 server CRON[24984]: pam_unix(cron:session): session op...)
sep 27 07:17:01 server CRON[24985]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts -...)
sep 27 07:17:01 server CRON[24984]: pam_unix(cron:session): session cl...t
sep 27 07:30:01 server CRON[24989]: pam_unix(cron:session): session op...)
sep 27 07:30:01 server CRON[24990]: (root) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/an...)
sep 27 07:39:01 server CRON[25234]: pam_unix(cron:session): session op...)
sep 27 07:39:01 server CRON[25235]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/s...)
sep 27 07:39:01 server CRON[25234]: pam_unix(cron:session): session cl...t
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Your answer assumes Debian (or derivate), and `systemd` as `init`

Comment: @heemayl Yes, true, I added an edit with that information.